# A bijective map from $\mathbb R\setminus \{1\}$ to $\mathbb R\setminus \{1,2,3\}$

Tags: real-analysis

How to think of finding a bijective map from $\mathbb R\setminus \{1\}$ to $\mathbb R\setminus \{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: What's the definition of a bijective map or which properties it preserves ?

Comment: He doesn't say the function has to be continuous :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bijection is between an infinite set and a subset of its. It is easy to make such bijections when the infinite set is well ordered, like $\Bbb N$: just count the element of the subset in order.

Here the infinite set is uncountable, and it has no easily definable well order. Well, just take a countable subset that contains the elements that are gone in the subset, make the bijection there and then expand this bijection with the identity for the remaining elements of the set.

Define for $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x+2&\text{ if }x\in\Bbb Z,x\ge 2\\x&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Since OP appears to be asking for intuition on how to solve the problem, it might also be worth it to add a word or two on how you came up with the solution.